# How to limit a switch case by an actual type in Swift

Tags: swift, enums, pattern-matching

I want to match a case in a Swift enum with an associated value based on a protocol. Specifically I want to limit a case to the actual type of the associated value, and I'm unsure if that is even possible.

```
protocol MyProtocol {}

extension Int:MyProtocol {}
extension Double:MyProtocol {}

enum MyEnum {
   case something(MyProtocol)
   case nothing
}

let somethingInt = .something(10)
let somethingDouble = .something(10.0)

switch somethingInt {
   case .something(let aValueInt):
   !!! I want to figure out how to limit this case to a double or an int
   case .something(let aValueDouble):
   !!! I want to figure out how to limit this case to a double or an int
   case .nothing:
   break
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that compiles and works correctly:

```
    protocol MyProtocol {}

    extension Int:MyProtocol {}
    extension Double:MyProtocol {}

    enum MyEnum {
        case something(MyProtocol)
        case nothing
    }

    let somethingInt = MyEnum.something(10)
    let somethingDouble = MyEnum.something(11.0)

    switch somethingInt { // and try it with somethingDouble instead
    case .something(let aValueInt as Int): print(aValueInt)
    case .something(let aValueDouble as Double): print(aValueDouble)
    case .something(_): break
    case .nothing: break
    }
```